# Creating native async function in Node.js

Tags: node.js

How can I create an asynchronous function in native Javascript without using `setTimeout`, `setImmediate` or `process.nextTick`?

Comment: use promise / deferred https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise or https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: @TommyDDD 'Regular' functions in javascript are not async by default by any means - OP might wanna take a peak at this though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @kwan245 promises are not async. node.js runs on a single thread. in order for something to be truly async you have to start another process (hopefully on a different core than the one running your main node.js process). that's what I am asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean *concurrent* code and not *async*.

The closer you can get to concurrent code in JavaScript without faking it using timers is by using the [WebWorker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) in the browser, or [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) in Node.js.

> Web Workers provide a simple means for web content to run scripts in
>   background threads.

Any code running in a WebWorker is independent of the 'main' thread - thus running concurrently in a sense.

Comment: Good answer. And before using check browser compatibility list at bottom of reference.

Comment: I was wondering about node.js, not the browser, but this helps anyway

Comment: @AlexMills I'm pretty sure it applies on node.js as well

Comment: Yes, but I think the child_process (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)  core module in Node.js is more applicable than Web Workers; I might change the accepted answer if I get a better one.